# Facebook's Authentication Redirection Loop

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

Using Facebook's example code:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/
and FB_ignited for CodeIgniter:
https://bitbucket.org/deth4uall/facebook-ignited I get an infuriating redirection loop after authentication.

Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: [Facebook Ignited](https://github.com/Necromnius/Facebook-Ignited) v1.1.2 resolves this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used a static file to handle the Facebook call back like so:

```
<?php

/*
    Callback redirect to get around CodeIgniters odd clean url analness
*/

$domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$controller = $_GET['controller'];
$code = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
header("Location: http://$domain/$controller?$code");
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a facebook auth / session / post & get variable problem.
And you might be experiencing the same one. 
Use `header ('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"');` at the top of your html output.